# Multiple redirects in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

After creating my middleware I get multiple redirects in my Laravel app, There is definitely something I am doing wrong but 
I don't know where.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $route = Route::currentRouteName();

    if($route!= "dashboard" || $route != "verify.again")
    {

        if(! is_null($request->user()) && ! $request->user()->verified) {
            return redirect()->route("verify.again");
        }
        elseif(!$request->user()->mobile){
            return redirect()->route("verify.again");
        }
         else{
             return $next($request);
        }


    }


    return $next($request);
}
```

Controller

```
public function index(){

    $user = Auth::user();
    if(!$user->verified)
    {
        return view("dashboard.verification.index", ["verify"=>"email", ]);
    }
    elseif(!$user->mobile)
    {
        return view("dashboard.verification.index", ["verify"=>"mobile", ]);
    }

    return view("dashboard.usermaster");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement will always be `true` for the `verify.again` route, because `"verify.again"` is always different than `"dashboard"`. This leads to an endless loop of redirects to the same route and middleware. So the solution might actually be to just replace the OR `||` with an AND `&&`:

```
if($route != "dashboard" && $route != "verify.again") {
    // your code here...
}
```